# How to play audio as it's being generated with Python on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, audio, raspberry-pi

I am trying to create a synthesizer with my Raspberry Pi and some capacitive touch sensors. I am able to generate a numpy array of doubles from -1 to 1 such that when they are played, it sounds like a guitar string being plucked. As of right now, my only way of playing the audio is to put the contents of the numpy array into a wavfile using the scipy library and play the wavfile with `os.system('omxplayer ' + file_name)`. My goal is to be playing the audio continuously or in small chunks rather than wait for the whole 5 second file to be generated and playing that, so I can overlay the sound of different 'strings' being plucked. Is there a specific library or module that allows me to do this?

Comment: I don't know any module which can read and play music file in chunks - maybe create many small audio data instead of one big data. And then you could play firs small wavfile and create next one.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to respond. I have tried to make several small wavfiles and played one after the other but there is a noticeable gap in between each file being played.

Comment: maybe using `pygame` [mixer](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html) or [music](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html) it would play without gap - it doesn't have to run external program. And probably it play in thread so it doesn't block main thread which can do other things.